# Copying complex XML data from API into Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity in ADF which calls a SOAP endpoint stores the results in Azure SQL Database.  This is what the response looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getTimesheetResponse xmlns:ns="http://services">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://objects.services/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax21:Timesheet">
                <ax21:endDate>2021/04/17</ax21:endDate>
                <ax21:entriesAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ax21:entriesOther xsi:type="ax21:TimesheetEntry">
                    <ax21:entryHours>2.0</ax21:entryHours>
                    <ax21:timesheetId>16532459835</ax21:timesheetId>
                </ax21:entriesOther>
                <ax21:entriesProject xsi:type="ax21:TimesheetEntry">
                    <ax21:entryHours>8.0</ax21:entryHours>
                    <ax21:timesheetId>16532459835</ax21:timesheetId>
                </ax21:entriesProject>
                    <ax21:entryHours>6.0</ax21:entryHours>
                    <ax21:timesheetId>16532459835</ax21:timesheetId>
                </ax21:entriesProject>
                <ax21:startDate>2021/04/11</ax21:startDate>
                <ax21:summaryNotes></ax21:summaryNotes>
                <ax21:timesheetId>16532459835</ax21:timesheetId>
                <ax21:timesheetPeriodId>11507374</ax21:timesheetPeriodId>
                <ax21:userId>1767426015</ax21:userId>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:getTimesheetResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So the object `<ax21:entriesOther>` can either be a single object or an array and the object `<ax21:entriesProject>` is usually an array. In the copy activity I have set up the mapping in such a way that it treats `<ax21:entriesProject>` as a collection reference and I did the same for `<ax21:entriesOther>`.  However, if I get only one entry in `<ax21:entriesOther>` no data is copied like in the response shared above.  How can I update the mapping or what should I do, so I get the data into my sql table irrespective of whether it is a single object or an array?

Mapping for `<ax21:entriesProject>` and `ax21:entriesOther>` except that the collection reference is different.
[image]

If I map as an object like this, it works fine.  But I want the copy activity to handle both arrays and single object.
[image]

Comment: Is there a label missing in the example? Missing one `<ax21:entriesProject xsi:type="ax21:TimesheetEntry">`?

Comment: I have truncated some data.  But all the labels are there

Comment: I'm facing this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QJUh.png).  : (